# How to access and use Scripting.FileSystemObject from Script#

Tags: c#, scripting, script#, activexobject, filesystemobject

I need to access file information such as file size.

I can create the ActiveXObject:

ActiveXObject fileSystem = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

But now, how should I access the methods for FileSystemObject?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Script.Windows.dll assembly - the import library has already been created - and comes along with Script#.

Also look at the Script Gadget project template - it includes some bootstrapper script that goes hand-in-hand with Script.Windows.dll ... basically a script-friendly wrapper for doing the equivalent of new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an import library that defines what methods are available to the Scripting.FileSystemObject class.